# What time does the Tbilisi to Istanbul bus depart?

Tags: georgia-country, buses, turkey, tbilisi, istanbul

I know there are buses running between Istanbul Turkey and Tbilisi Georgia.

I know they take about 30 hours and cost about $35.

**What I don't know is what time they depart Tbilisi and what time roughly they arrive in Istanbul.**

I also don't know whether there is just one company or several, and whether they leave from Ortachala or Didube station or some from each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following my own advice from my answer to [Is there an equivalent to “The Man in Seat Sixty-One” for bus travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/4469/1317), I looked on the [Lonely Planet page for Tbilisi](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/georgia/tbilisi/transport/getting-there-away):

> A minifleet of four or five buses run by different companies departs
>   **at noon** for Istanbul (US$40, 27 hours) via the border at Sarpi, Hopa,
>   Rize

They leave from the second bus terminal:

> Ortachala bus station (753433; Gulia 1) is something of a backwater,
>   about 2.5km southeast of the Old Town.